# tkinter: заштриховать определенную область

Tags: python, tkinter, математика, canvas

Моя программа строит сечение подшипника. Нужно закрасить определенную площадь фигуры. Не могу найти нужный метод. Подскажите пожалуйста, что лучше использовать?

```
import tkinter as tk

# Create the main window
win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("400x400")

# Create a Canvas widget
c = tk.Canvas(win, width=410, height=410)
c.pack()

c.create_arc(10,10,20,20,
             start = 180, extent = -90,
             style=tk.ARC)

c.create_arc(100,20,90,10,
             start = 0,extent = 90,
             style=tk.ARC)

c.create_arc(10,400,20,410,
             start = 180, extent = 90,
             style=tk.ARC)

c.create_arc(90,400,100,410,
             start = 270, extent = 90,
             style=tk.ARC)

c.create_line(100,405,100,15)
c.create_line(15,410,95,410)
c.create_line(10,15,10,405)
c.create_line(95,10,15,10)

c.create_oval(23,28,87,93)

c.create_line(10,21,55,28)
c.create_line(80,39,100,39)
c.create_line(80,81,100,81)
c.create_line(10,81,30,81)
c.create_line(24,81,26,74)
c.create_line(87,81,84,74)

c.create_arc(90,100,100,110,
             start = 0,extent = -90,
             style=tk.ARC)

c.create_line(95,110,15,110)

c.create_arc(10,100,20,110,
             start = 270, extent = -90,
             style=tk.ARC)


#рисуем нижную часть
c.create_oval(23,327,87,392)
c.create_line(10,399,55,392)
c.create_line(10,339,30,339)
c.create_line(80,381,100,381)
c.create_line(80,339,100,339)
c.create_arc(90,310,100,320,
             start =0,extent = 90,
             style=tk.ARC)
c.create_line(95,310,15,310)
c.create_arc(10,310,20,320,
             start = 90,extent = 90,
             style=tk.ARC)
c.create_line(24,339,26,346)
c.create_line(87,339,84,346)


win.mainloop()
```

[image: Сам разрез который нужен]

Comment: Нет такого готового метода. Только самому как-то реализовывать.

Comment: Можете тогда что-нибудь подсказать

Comment: Я бы вообще не делал это средствами tkinter. Если нужна просто статическая картинка, то картинку бы и вставил. Если нужна какая-то параметризация, типа в окне регулируются размеры, и они отображаются на рисунке — все равно бы искал какую-то библиотеку, которая умеет такое делать, потом просто результат отображал в окне.

Comment: я бы тоже так не делал, но курсовая работа требует использовать именно эту библиотеку, поэтому ищу какой-либо метод для решения данной проблемы

Comment: Нужно рассчитывать пересечения каждой линии штриховки с каждым сегментом ограничивающего контура. Т.е. брать уравнение прямой штриха, брать уравнение (прямой или дуги) секции контура, решать как систему. Проверять, что точка пересечения находится внутри сегмента (отрезка или дуги). Потом между противоположными точками пересечения строить "штрих".  Это в общих чертах.